# как проверить заполнены ли n количество ячеек массива определённым значением

Tags: java, массивы

мне нужно проверить есть ли в массиве n количество свободных ячеек(со значениями "0" где "1" - заполнен) int[] array=int[10];
представим такой массив {0,1,0,1,0,0,0,1,1,0};
нужно вычислить n количество ячеек в массиве, где n к примеру  ровняется трём

Comment: а в чем именно проблема?

Comment: я не знаю как это сделать

Comment: с помощью цикла `for` пройтись по массиву и посчитать количество нулей, а потом сравнить с `n`.

Comment: @Piligrim именно в этом смысл учебной задачи: заставить вас узнать, как это делать, а не переложить решение задачи на кого-то. помочь - это всегда пожалуйста. сделать за вас - это к ребятам , которые пишут чужие курсовые

Comment: @Дмитрий, ваша правда.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.InputMismatchException;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Main {

    private static final int VALUE = 0;

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        final int[] array = new int[]{0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0};

        System.out.print("Введите N: ");
        final int n;
        try (final Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in)) {
            n = scanner.nextInt();
        } catch (RuntimeException ex) {
            System.err.println("Во время считывания переменной произошла ошибка!");
            ex.printStackTrace();
            return;
        }

        final String result = (n == getCountOfValue(array, VALUE)) ?
                String.format("Число %d совпадает с количеством числа %d в массиве", n, VALUE) :
                String.format("Число %d не совпадает с количеством числа %d в массиве", n, VALUE);

        System.out.println(result);
    }

    private static long getCountOfValue(int[] array, int value) {
        return Arrays.stream(array)
                .filter(x -> x == value)
                .count();
    }

}
```